# externalIvySettingsURL with SBT 1.0.4 Play Framework

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.0, ivy

In my build environment, we manage our own ivy repository. In my `build.sbt` file, I use `externalIvySettingsURL` to define the locations of the dependencies.

I am able to successfully run `sbt` in my project directory, and sbt seemingly finds all of the dependencies associated with the project (eg: sbt will properly create and populate the .sbt and .ivy2 folders). When I attempt to run `sbt compile`, I get the following stack trace:

```
[info] Compiling 7 Scala sources and 21 Java sources to C:\Users\ian.gabriel\workspace\Utils\play\target\scala-2.12\classes ...
:: loading settings :: file = L:\Libs\ivySettings\ivysettings.xml
[info] Attempting to fetch org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.12:1.0.5.
[error] ## Exception when compiling 28 sources to C:\Users\ian.gabriel\workspace\Utils\play\target\scala-2.12\classes
[error] For input string: "null"
[error] scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.parseBoolean(StringLike.scala:327)
[error] scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toBoolean(StringLike.scala:286)
[error] scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toBoolean$(StringLike.scala:286)
[error] scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toBoolean(StringOps.scala:29)
[error] sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.retrieve(IvyActions.scala:385)
[error] sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$6(IvyActions.scala:213)
```

I found a related github issue that seems close, but should have made it into the version of SBT that I am currently using: https://github.com/sbt/librarymanagement/issues/110

The github issue points to a different part of the `sbt.internal.librarymanagement` code than the problem i am currently having.

After removing the `externalIvySettingsURL` setting from my `build.sbt` file, the compile process executes as expected (throwing a bunch of compile errors for symbols that cannot be found, which is normal)

```
[info] Compiling 7 Scala sources and 21 Java sources to C:\Users\ian.gabriel\workspace\Utils\play\target\scala-2.12\classes ...
[info] Non-compiled module 'compiler-bridge_2.12' for Scala 2.12.4. Compiling...
[info]   Compilation completed in 9.776s.
```

It seems that SBT is not attempting to compile the compiler-bridge module when I use `externalIvySettingsURL`. Running `compile` in the sbt console after this module has been compiled seems to work properly. I have other developers who will run into this problem the first time that a play project is compiled, or when their `~/.sbt` folder is deleted.

Is this a bug in SBT that I should be reporting, or am I doing something incorrectly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in SBT as far as I can tell. I made a issue on their github:

https://github.com/sbt/librarymanagement/issues/195

My fix for this problem was to add

`<property name="sbt.managedChecksums" value="False"/>`

to my ivySettings.xml, which stopped throwing the exception. I am not sure what the default value for this key should be if not present, nor did I have the time to fully read the SBT code to figure out what this setting is used for. This did manage to fix my build, but it could have other side effects I am not aware of. Good luck!